# Click on Anchor tag is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Click on Anchor tag is not working..Here is my code:

```
$('#selectall').onclick(function () {
    console.log("Hello");
});

<li>
  <a class="selectall" id="selectall">
     <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> Select All
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the click event!

the problem is that "onclick" isn't supposed to used this way. You can either do

```
$('#selectall').click(function ....)
```

or

```
$('#selectall').on('click', function ....)
```

a

```
$('#selectall').onclick(function ... )
```

does not exist for jQuery. 'onclick' is by default a javascript function.

```js
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
      alert("Hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a class="selectall" id="selectall"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> Select All</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using jquery it seems, so instead of `onclick` you should use `click`

Comment: there is an id = selectall

Comment: the `a` element has the id "selectall" if you look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

just apply

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)".... >
```

or

```
 <a href="#".... >
```

and use method  as "click" not "onclick"

Answer (score 0):

Since you also id-ed it with "selectall", the "#" is allright. You do need
`$('#selectall').click(function () {`
tho.

Also, when is your js executed? If the above js-code is executed BEFORE the html containg the anchor tag is rendered, it will fail, because there is nothing yet to bind it to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the $ is jQuery so use `.click()` not `.onclick()`

otherwise, the vanillaJS code is

```
document.getElementById('selectall').addEventListener('click',function(){
    console.log('hello');
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use delegate events, so a.selectall elements can be added/removed dynamically w/out messing up your click listener.

```
$("body").on("click", ".selectall", function(evt){
    //click handler code here
});
```